# Setting up Kubernetes Mock Server Using Golang

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup a mock server using which I can test performance of my application on higher scales. Basically my Go server collects metrics for different K8s Objects i.e. Nodes, pods, etc. I am using kubernetes clientset provided by **k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes** package. The code I have written in go server is as below:

```
for {
        podResources, err := Clientset.CoreV1().RESTClient().Get().Namespace(v1.NamespaceAll).
            Resource("pods").
            VersionedParams(&v1.ListOptions{
                Limit:    config.Manager.K8SRESLIMIT,
                Continue: podReqContinue}, scheme.ParameterCodec).DoRaw(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, K8sCollectionTimestamps{}, err
        }
        // Do some processing on data received is podResources
        if podReqContinue == "" {
            break
        }
    }
```

When this code is executed it sends data in multiple chunks until **podReqContinue != ""** in response data.

**For Example,**

If there are total 1000 records and **Limit** is set to 100, then data is returned by clientset in 10 batches/chunks.

Now, the question is, how can I set up a mock data server which can return large data in chunks properly so that I can simulate and test this block of code for cluster which has 30k or 40k pods.